# Is there any observational test that could be done to approve\ disapprove the Tired Light theory?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, space-expansion

[Tired light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_light) is alternative explanation for the redshift-distance relationship and for the metric expansion of space. The suggestion is if photons lost energy over time through collisions with other particles in a regular way, the more distant objects would appear redder than more nearby ones.

Edit: The point of my question is to figure out an alternative explanation for the red-shift caused by the expansion and I just found out that I refer to the [Tired Light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_light). My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Did you ever try to transform into the resting frame of a photon?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29082/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I made animation describe my expansion model here : http://giphy.com/gifs/26tnk7laBoNMBd7Ik

Comment: Now a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156618/

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a spherical [wavefront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront) i.e. light radiating outwards from a [point source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_source) with spherical symmetry. But suppose you have two such point sources near enough to each other that their wavefronts overlap. Now your expansion model has to have space expanding simultaneously in opposite directions.

Consider also that a wavefront can be any shape. For example it can be a [plane wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave) or with enough effort you can create a wavefront with any shape you want. To describe all these different waves as expanding spacetime rapidly becomes impossibly complicated.