# Can anything other than recessional motion cause a redshift?

Tags: doppler-effect, redshift

The question pretty much says it all. Is there any force, or circumstance, or anything that we know of that can affect the measurement of a red shift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Other explanation for cosmological redshift?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143978/)

Answer (score 2):

Redshift can be also caused by gravity, in which case it is called gravitational redshift, related of course to gravitational time dilation.

In regards to cosmology, some people hypothesized that what is perceived as recessional redshift might be caused by some other mechanism by which light loses its energy when traversing cosmic distances, these theories fall under the collective name "tired light theories" and are in contradiction with observation (see Weinberg, Cosmology section 1.7)

Comment: A point that is not taken in attention usually is the position of bodies in different gravitation potentials, where the result of the redshift or blueshift is not related to gravitational time dilation. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172854/do-photons-lose-energy-due-to-gravitational-redshift-if-so-where-does-the-lost/173045#173045